# How to display data from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, join

I have two different tables:

**`tbl_cinema`**

- `cinema_id`
- `cinema_name`
- `cinema_address`
- `cinema_phone`
- `cinema_email`

and

**`tbl_cinema_level`**

- `cinema_level_id`
- `cinema_level_name`
- `cinema_id`

How can I display the `cinema_name` and `cinema_level_name`?

---

My method for displaying the data:

```
public void displayCinema() 
{
    Utility ut = new Utility();
    SqlConnection con = ut.openconnection();
    string query = "select tbl_cinema.cinema_name, tbl_cinema_level.cinema_level_name from tbl_cinema LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_cinema_level on tbl_cinema.cinema_id=tbl_cinema_level.cinema_id group by tbl_cinema.cinema_name, tbl_cinema_level.cinema_level_name;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        sb.Append("<ul><li><h3>" + dr["cinema_name"].ToString() + "</h3>
                   <ul><li>" + dr["cinema_level_name"].ToString() + "</li></ul></li>");
    }
    Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

All the cinema levels should be listed under the cinema name that it belongs.

**Edit:**

```
 <div id="display_cinema">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
 </div>
```

I want to list it as ,,

**cinema name 1** 
*cinema level name 1 

cinema level name 2*

**cinema name 2** 
*cinema level name 1 

cinema level name 2*

Instead i am getting output as follows..

**cinema name 1** 
*cinema level name 1*

**cinema name 1** 
*cinema level name 2* and so on..

Comment: Each iteration through the datareader will create a new unordered list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT C.cinema_name,CL.cinema_level_name
FROM tbl_cinema C JOIN tbl_cinema_level ON
C.cinema_id = CL.cinema_id
```

You have to use like

```
 string query = "SELECT C.cinema_name,CL.cinema_level_name FROM tbl_cinema C JOIN tbl_cinema_level ON C.cinema_id = CL.cinema_id"
```

[JOIN in SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

> In SQL joins are used to get data from two or more tables based on
>   relationship between some of the columns in tables. In most of the
>   cases we will use primary key of first table and foreign key of
>   secondary table to get data from tables by using this relationship we
>   can reduce the duplication of data in every table.

Comment: thx for the reply. i do know about using joins but i have been having problem while listing them by binding in html code as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some problem while you are appending the `formatted html tags` to `StringBuilder` below:

```
sb.Append("<ul><li><h3>" + dr["cinema_name"].ToString() + "</h3>
               <ul><li>dr["cinema_level_name"].ToString()</li></ul></li>");
                       ^                                 ^              ^
                       |                                 |              |
```

Try to replace with the following statement:

```
sb.Append("<ul><li><h3>" + dr["cinema_name"].ToString() + "</h3>" + 
              "<ul><li>" + dr["cinema_level_name"].ToString() + "</li></ul></li></ul>");
```